# Выражение должно иметь тип класса C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, операторы

Всё что написано в функции:

```
private: System::Void textBox1_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e) {
        char number = e.KeyChar;
    }
```

Выдаёт ошибки:

1. > `e` выражение должно иметь тип класса
2. > C2228 выражение слева от `.KeyChar` должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение.

В чём заключается ошибка?

Замена `e.KeyChar` на `e->KeyChar` помогла, только теперь новая проблема с

```
private: System::Void textBox1_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e) {
        char number = e->KeyChar;
        if (!Char.IsDigit(number))
        {
            e->Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Жалуется на `if (!Char.IsDigit(number))`

Comment: Не следует изменять свой исходный вопрос, рекурсивно добавляя к нему новые вопросы. Это ставит в заблуждение пишущих вам ответы и читающих вопрос и ответы. Лучше задавайте новый вопрос, если возникла новая проблема.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что имеется в виду

```
char number = e->KeyChar;
              ^^^^
```

Для второго сообщения об ошибке попробуйте написать

```
if (!Char::IsDigit(number))
         ^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Нужно будет более детально изучить эти операторы :D

Comment: @Виталий Если помогло, то закрывайте вопрос, выбрав ответ, который вам помог, чтобы вопрос не был подвешенным.